# Which XSS OWASP Rule

Tags: javascript, xss, owasp

Using the OWASP checklist, which is the correct way protect this situation?  This is url inside of a javascript string where a url parameter needs to have xss protection.

Problem:

```
<script>
    var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% url.baddata %>'  
    dosomeAjax(u);
</script>
```

Possible solution 1:

```
var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForURL(url.baddata) %>'
```

Possible solution 2:

```
var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForJavaScript(url.baddata) %>'
```

Possible solution 3:

```
var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForJavaScript(encodeForURL(url.baddata)) %>'
```

Comment: That totally depends on what doSomeAjax does ?

Comment: What if doSomeAjax did: $.ajax({
  url: u,
  success: function(data) {
    eval(data);
  }
});

Comment: UPDATE – to try to set this in the proper context,  I’m narrowing the problem down this:  $.ajax({url: “xyz.html?x=<%url.baddata%>”}) so there is no variable u and there is no success or return function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 3 should be used:

```
//solution 3:
var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForJavaScript(encodeForURL(url.baddata)) %>';
```

It is easier to see that this is correct if we rewrite the expression as:

```
var u = '<% encodeForJavaScript("xyz.html?x=" + encodeForURL(url.baddata)) %>';
```

First, we are creating a safe URL by appending `baddata` to a string constant, using the appropriate escape function.  Then we are taking that safe URL and placing it in a JavaScript string, so we have to call the JavaScript escape function.

Comment: I believe solution 3 should be used as well. This guy does a good job explaining it. It's an OWASP e-mail thread so read from bottom to top. lists.owasp.org/pipermail/esapi-dev/2012-March/002105.html

Comment: @Cheran Shunmugavel Hi, can you tell me please do I need to include a owasp js file to use these functions: encodeForJavaScript() encodeForHTML() etc.? I have read the owasp docs and searched on github but im still unsure where to get the files that i need to include in my project? My project is written in HTML, javascript, JSON and php. thanks –

Comment: @Sarah, I'm sorry, but I don't know. I just used the function names that were given in the question.

Comment: @Cheran Shunmugavel That's ok thanks. I found the js files here :) https://code.google.com/archive/p/owasp-esapi-js/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question.  After working with this scenario over and over again, the solution is very apparent and the reason is too.

First and foremost:  Any string which is being inserted into javascript needs to be javascript safe.  This always needs to happen no matter what:

```
<script>
  var x = "<% encodeForJavaScript(someCrazyString) %>";
</script>
```

The goal here is secure this statement.  Since this is javascript code, treat it as javascript--this is not a url so url encoding is is incorrect.

Now if the `x` is going to be used in a url, it needs to be encoded as a url.

The only thing is `x` is now a javascript string.  So server-side encoding is impossible because the string been pushed out of the middle tier and is now living and breathing in the browser.

The solution is to use javascript's url encoding function:  `encodeURIComponentz()`

```
<script>
  var x = "<% encodeForJavaScript(someCrazyString) %>";
  x = x + '234'
  var url = 'http://localhost/abc.cfm?x=' + encodeURIComponent(x)
</script>
```

There is never a reason to use 2 server-side XXS encoding functions.  Always use a single server-side encoding function and use the correct server-side function for the context:

Url:

```
<a href="xyz.jsp?x=<% encodeForURL(someString) %>" target="_blank" >click here</a>
```

js:

```
 <script>
   var x = "<% encodeForJavaScript(someCrazyString) %>";
 </script>
```

json:

```
 <script>
   var x = {"x"  : "<% encodeForJSONinJS(someCrazyString) %>"};
 </script>
```

### Update (a few years later)

Performing 2 server-side encodings will achieve the same result as encoding once on the server and once in the client. So solution 3 is correct, if and only if `var u` stays in url scope.

The danger of doing 2 server-side encodings is that you may only use the snippet in the context in which it was **first** encoded.

Take the example above and add 1 more line:

```
 <script>
     var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForJavaScript(encodeForURL(url.baddata)) %>
     dosomeAjax(u);
     document.getElementById('someDivTag').innerHTML= u;
 </script>
```

Now there are problems because u is url encoded and not html encoded.  (In this particular case, this does not present an xss variability as you cannot break out of an url encoded string into js scope--nonetheless there are lots of other cases where a string will need to be encoded 2x).

For flexibility, my preference is to encode once on the server and as needed in the client as:

```
 <script>
     var x = "<% encodeForJavaScript(someCrazyString) %>";
     var u = 'http://localhost/abc.cfm?x=' + encodeURIComponent(x)
     dosomeAjax(u);
     document.getElementById('someDivTag').innerHTML= u.toHtml();
 </script>
```

where `toHtml()` is:

```
    var __entityMap = {
            "&": "&amp;",
            "<": "&lt;",
            ">": "&gt;",
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&#39;',
            "/": '&#x2F;'
    };

    String.prototype.toHtml = function() {
            return String(this).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {  
                    return __entityMap[s];
            });
    }
```

I am checking Cheran Shunmugavel's answer as correct.

Comment: Just to make things fun...I've never found a string which is url encoded and dropped in to a javascript quoted var which is vulnerable...in other words...it seems like url encoded strings are safe in javascript...they will not mean the same thing as they will in a url--nonetheless they appear to be js safe--they would just need to be url decoded.  Even so, I still always use javascript encoding in javascript and url encoding for urls.

Comment: McGinty Hi, can you tell me please do I need to include a js library to use these functions: encodeForJavaScript() encodeForHTML() etc.? I have read the owasp docs and searched on github but im still unsure how to use it within my app? My app is written in HTML, javascript, JSON and php. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForURL(encodeForJavaScript(url.baddata)) %>'
```

EncodeForURL should be last.

`<`insert obligatory 'eval is bad, what are you thinking ??'`>`

Comment: This is correct.  The string needs to be url encoded last so that it can be a valid url parameter, ie.  \x27 is invalid on the url where as %27 is valid. Then the webserver will decode the url to get the xss protected string which can then be executed as javascript.

BTW, the eval was for demonstration purposes only.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: After thinking about this, I’m not sure if the above answer is correct.   The problem is that once the server gets the url (via the ajax call), it would need to hex decode the x parameter in order to know its value.  

I’m guessing the answer is var u = 'xyz.html?x=<% encodeForURL(url.baddata) %>' 

What this boils down to is if a url encoded string is consider safe inside of a quotes.

Comment: No, we are in a url context inside a javascript context, so this answer isn't correct unfortunately.

Comment: For chars 1-255, the only difference between encodeForURL and encodeForJavaScript is one escapes with % and the other \x.   I’m really curious how someone can construct a harmful string inside of url.baddata which has been url encoded.

Comment: In this case, I would opt for visual clarity rather than technical correctness; it's much easier to verify (at least by eye) that you are applying the correct escaping if you see `encodeForJavaScript` there.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity A server worth its salt ( J2EE , PHP, BSP etc. ) will already decode the value or have a simple way to do that, also for this to work reliably you simply have to encodeURL, regardless of xss.

Comment: Yeah, the encodeURL has to be there and the last thing done.  I emailed Jeff Williams from Aspect Security (his email is on the owasp site as an author), and he said this:  "I think it’s 3.  Solution 1 doesn’t encode the '  so an attacker could inject another attribute.  Solution 2 would likely break legitimate URLs."  So that would make sense..... I am using a custom encodeURL which does encode ' to %27...I am about to check the actual function from owasp.

Comment: I just checked the owasp encodeURL function which is now built into Coldfusion and it also turns ' to %27. I have no way to easily check the what the java version does. So I’m still under the impression that solution 1 is ok.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity : You are confusing me: the parameter x will be part of data, right ? It is almost guaranteed that at that point, the %27 will be a ' again. Also, you should probably not do your own encodeURL but use a standard. Also, you could probably still do xss even without the quote.

Comment: It is hard to put this in context.   And like you said at the beginning, it a depends on the context.  So to try to set this in the proper context,  I’m narrowing the problem down this:  $.ajax({url: “xyz.html?x=<%url.baddata%>”}) so there is no variable u and there is no success or return function.

Comment: I was thinking, if there is still a hole in the security, the Aspect Security guys will find it, let us know if option 3 works for you. I still think my answer is more future proof, we agree we disagree I guess ;)