# ColdFusion Encoding Issue - encodeForHTML and encodeForJavascript Drops Backslashes

Tags: javascript, encoding, coldfusion, xss, esapi

To protect against Cross-site Scripting (XSS) I'm using what OWASP recommends, the [ESAPI (Enterprise Security API)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API).  [The esapi.jar file has been included with prior version of ColdFusion](http://damonmiller.github.io/esapi4cf/) but in CF10 you can now easily call some of these helpful functions: `encodeForJavascript()`, `encodeForHTML()`, `encodeForURL()`, `encodeForCSS()`, and `encodeForHTMLAttribute()`.

I am having troubles with `encodeForJavascript()`, I'm losing my backslash...

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfif isDefined("url.name")>
        <!--- Here is the problem, this is identical to the original ascii32to126 string except for one char is missing, the backslash between the brackets ...Z[]... --->
        #url.name#
        <cfabort>
    </cfif>

    <!---
    ASCII 32 thru 126
    !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
    In the line below I double up on the double-quotes and pounds in order to get the cfset to work
    --->
    <cfset ascii32to126 = "!""##$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~">

    <script>
        function locateTo(value)
        {
            window.location='thisPage.cfm?name='+encodeURIComponent(value);
            //alert('thisPage.cfm?name='+encodeURIComponent(value));
        }
        locateTo('#encodeForJavaScript(ascii32to126)#');
    </script>
</cfoutput>
```

I first call `encodeForJavaScript()` because we are in the JavaScript context.

Then I call `encodeURIComponent()` to make sure the URL is built properly.

Everything works fine but on the resulting page I have lost my backslash `\`.  What am I missing here?

(Yes, I am aware I also have to protect where I output `#url.name#`.  For this experiment I didn't do that because I needed to view the source to see if the string matched the original string.)

** **UPDATE** **  - I am running ColdFusion 10 with all the latest patches applied.  Problem seems to be in `encodeForJavaScript()`.

Fails with `JSStringFormat()` also.  Doing this shows the backslash is missing for both...

```
<cfset ascii32to126 = "!""##$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~">
<cfoutput>
    #encodeForHTML(encodeForJavaScript(ascii32to126))#
    <br><br>
    #encodeForHTML(JSStringFormat(ascii32to126))#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You don't need to view source: `<cfcontent reset type="text/plain">#url.name#<cfabort/>`

Comment: I just ran your code on Railo 4 and Chromium and it works fine - the backslash is present. Possibly a bug in encodeForJavaScript of whatever version of CF you're running, or in the encodeURIComponent implementation of whatever browser you tested with - you've not provided either piece of information.

Comment: I am running ColdFusion 10 with all the latest patches applied.  Seems to be in `encodeForJavaScript()`, simply doing this shows the backslash is missing... `<cfoutput>#encodeForJavaScript(ascii32to126)#</cfoutput>`

Comment: Hmmm. Does it work with JsStringFormat instead?

Comment: Nope, see update above.

Comment: Eh, I've just launched CF10 and JsStringFormat works fine - it correctly escapes the backslash. encodeForJavaScript does drop it though - https://gist.github.com/boughtonp/519876a5f77c6f4ddcf0

Comment: Note cfcontent text/plain - no need for encodeForHtml which is ALSO removing the backslash. (No `%5C` output)

Comment: I had a quick look at JARs - it looks like CF10 and Railo4 both use ESAPI v2.0.1 - but encodeForJavaScript and encodeForHtml are working in Railo, but not in CF10. Bugs like this is why [I recommend avoiding encodeForX functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239919/how-to-text-value-from-a-textbox-in-coldfusion#comment35575763_23243822).

Comment: I removed encodeForHTML() and I see the same now.  With `jsStringFormat()` I see the escaped backslash \\, but with `encodeForJavaScript()` the `\x5C` is missing.  Instead I see `...\x5B\x5D...`  Why would this be?  From the reading I've done the ESAPI is highly recommended by OWASP and others. .... Just saw your last comment, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the backslash is eaten by the following character - i.e. a single backslash alone is encoded, but with other characters it is lost. Dunno why... you'd have to ask Adobe that. :/

Comment: I've spoken with Damon Miller the ESAPI project leader before, I'll see if he has some insight into it.  Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2+ years later)  It appears to have since been fixed by Adobe or the ESAPI people.  All characters including the backslash are retained.  I am now running these versions...

> Server Product: ColdFusion
>
> Version: 11,0,09,299201
>
> Tomcat Version: 7.0.68.0
>
> Edition: Developer
>
> Operating System: Windows 10
>
> OS Version: 10.0
>
> Update Level: C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/lib/updates/chf11000009.jar
>
> Adobe Driver: 5.1.3 (Build 000094)
>
> Java Version: 1.8.0_91
>
> Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, we have been using all of the encodeForX functions for over a year now and only have problems when a developer uses the wrong context. We have strictly outlawed the use of HTMLEditFormat and have a Jenkins server check for it (among other outlawed functions & tags) as builds are run throughout the day.

You are encoding the string for JavaScript and then encoding it for URL. I believe you should be encoding for URL first, then encoding for JavaScript. There don't seem to be any lost characters when I compare the output to the un-encoded string.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfif isDefined("url.name")>
        <!--- Here is the problem, this is identical to the original ascii32to126 string except for one char is missing, the backslash between the brackets ...Z[]... --->
        #url.name#
        <cfabort>
    </cfif>

    <!---
    ASCII 32 thru 126
    !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
    In the line below I double up on the double-quotes and pounds in order to get the cfset to work
    --->
    <!--- Using Chr() to bypass character escaping. --->
    <cfset ascii32to126 = "!#chr(34)##chr(35)#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~">
    <cfdump var="#ascii32to126#" />

    <script>
        function locateTo(a, b) {
            console.log(a); // 1. JavaScript Encoded.
            console.log(b); // 2. URL encoded, then JavaScript encoded.
            console.log(decodeURIComponent(b));// 3. Matches JavaScript encoded.
            console.log( 'thisPage.cfm?name=' + b ); // 4. Correct string.
        }

        locateTo('#encodeForJavaScript(ascii32to126)#', '#encodeForJavaScript(encodeForURL(ascii32to126))#');
    </script>
</cfoutput>
```

**Console Output**

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ 

%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D%7E 

!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ 

thisPage.cfm?name=%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D%7E
```

Comment: Ah, yes, encode url first then js.  I actually knew that and mentioned the same exact thing a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488992/which-xss-owasp-rule/10491771#comment35538223_10491771 How easily I forget, need more RedBull :)  BUT, I took your code and ran it as is and I do not get the same results.  Lines 1 and 2 both have the backslash missing and line 3 `decodeURIComponent` dies with `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`.  Really strange.  I am CF version: 10,0,13,287689 and Java version 1.7.0_51.

Comment: Even if I can get it working it wouldn't be my ideal solution.  `locateTo` is very simple example of something else in my system.  It represents a low-level function used by 1000s of calls.  I want the protection to happen there.  I'd rather not have the other programmers have to remember to always do both like you demonstrated: `#encodeForJavaScript(encodeForURL(ascii32to126))#`.  But I can't think of a way around it.

Comment: I get that Gordon, but we have strict coding standards and it's up to every developer (60 right now, about to be 80) to make sure they're calling the correct encoder under the correct context. We actually rolled out a UDF to abstract the individual functions: safeOutput( text, encoder ). We also have an evolving JavaScript library full of standardized functions like your locateTo. No one rolls their own unless it is specific to the current page's logic.

Comment: safeOutput(), that's a good idea.  Still don't know why the backslash is not showing for me though.

Comment: Is it in this part of the string? "[\\]"

Comment: Nope, I've viewed source and did console.log it's just not there after using encodeForHTML or encodeForJavascript.  @PeterBoughton is also having the same results as me. Will play with it more tomorrow, have left office.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have our own custom encoding function called ddj()...

```
<!---
Author: @Brian McGinity
custom version of jsStringFormat/encodeForJavaScript
--->
<cffunction name="ddj" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="temp" required="yes" type="string">
    <!---
    <cfset var z = jsStringFormat(arguments.temp)>
    <cfreturn z>
    --->
    <cfset var buf = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuffer")>
    <cfset var len = Len(arguments.temp)>
    <cfset var char = "">
    <cfset var charcode = 0>
    <cfset var bad   = ' >%}\~];?@&<##{|^[`/:=$+"' & "'">
    <cfset buf.ensureCapacity(JavaCast("int", len+40))>
    <cfif NOT len><cfreturn arguments.temp></cfif>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#len#" index="xmlIdx">
        <cfset char = mid(arguments.temp,xmlIdx,1)>
        <cfset charcode = asc(char)>
        <cfif charcode LT 32 or charcode gt 126>
            <cfset buf.append(JavaCast("string", ""))>
        <cfelse>
            <cfif find(char, bad) gt 0>
                <cfset buf.append(JavaCast("string",  "\u00" & right("0" & formatBaseN(charcode,16),2) ))>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset buf.append(JavaCast("string", char))>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn buf.toString()>
</cffunction>
```

Using `ddj()` I can pass the ascii32to126 string into the function, then do the `encodeURIComponent` on it, then locate to a page and print it and the string is exactly the same.  Seems to work great.  But doing it this way I am encoding for JS first, then for the URL second.  That doesn't seem right.  I've always thought it had to be the other way around **([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10488992/3112803))**. So I'm trying to figure out if I can break it.  Here is the test case that appears to work...

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfif isDefined("url.name")>
        #url.name#
        <cfabort>
    </cfif>

    <!--- !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ --->
    <cfset ascii32to126 = "!""##$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~">

    <script>
        function goToUrl(value)
        {
            window.location='thisPage.cfm?name='+encodeURIComponent(value);
            //alert('thisPage.cfm?name='+encodeURIComponent(value));
        }
        goToUrl('#ddj(ascii32to126)#');
    </script>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Hi G.  I've learned quit a lot about xss since my SO post referenced above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488992/which-xss-owasp-rule)...here's my findings:  if you're dropping a string in to javascript, then it needs js encoding.  This needs to happen so that any and every string will be protected as it stits in js.   If that string is then going to passed into a url (while remaining in javascript), then use javascirpt's `encodeURIComponent()`.   It is a mistake to url encode a string and then place it javascript.

Comment: What up B?! OK, so you are saying my answer above is correct?  That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, you have it right.  I've added an answer to my post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488992/which-xss-owasp-rule/23400671#23400671